# I have a DACPAC of the "ideal" version of a database, and also some production databases which may differ. How can I get a report comparing them?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019, dacpac

This DACPAC is used for test deployments; however we've been unable to use it for production deployments because somehow all the production databases got out of sync. I was going to run Schema Compare in Visual Studio to compare each database to the DACPAC in turn and write down all the discrepancies, but there were a lot more discrepancies than I expected and it would take forever to write them all down. Is there any way to get a report generated for each database that details the differences between all database objects in that database as compared to the DACPAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SqlPackage.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15) is the deployment engine used by Visual Studio Schema Compare, and it has additional options:

> SqlPackage.exe is a command-line utility that automates the following
> database development tasks:
>
> Version: Returns the build number of the SqlPackage application. Added
> in version 18.6.
>
> Extract: Creates a data-tier application (.dacpac) file containing the
> schema or schema and user data from a connected SQL database.
>
> Publish: Incrementally updates a database schema to match the schema
> of a source .dacpac file. If the database does not exist on the
> server, the publish operation creates it. Otherwise, an existing
> database is updated.
>
> Export: Exports a connected SQL database - including database schema
> and user data - to a BACPAC file (.bacpac).
>
> Import: Imports the schema and table data from a BACPAC file into a
> new user database.
>
> DeployReport: Creates an XML report of the changes that would be made
> by a publish action.
>
> DriftReport: Creates an XML report of the changes that have been made
> to a registered database since it was last registered.
>
> Script: Creates a Transact-SQL incremental update script that updates
> the schema of a target to match the schema of a source.
>
> The SqlPackage.exe command line allows you to specify these actions
> along with action-specific parameters an

Comment: Oh, cool, thanks! So I tried running the Script action of SqlPackage.exe, and for some reason it's telling me that all the DB objects need to be created? Shouldn't it be ignoring the ones that already exist and scripting changes to ones that have been modified?

Comment: What I did is I made a batch file which looks something like this:  `sqlpackage /Action:Script /DeployReportPath:%1.%2.xml /DeployScriptPath:%1.%2.sql /TargetDatabaseName:%1 /TargetPassword:NotMyRealPassword /TargetServerName:%1.NotOurRealDomain.us /TargetUser:MyUsername /SourceFile:%1.dacpac` - then I just run it with the arguments being the name of the system I'm connecting to and the name of the database I want to compare to the DACPAC. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Oh, of course. I specified the wrong database name; I used the server name in its place. Oops! Now I'm getting these nice SQL scripts and XML reports. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

There is a new Powershell module : DACPACComparator
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/DacpacComparator/2.0
that compares the 2 DACPAC and provides you the difference.
You can leverage that.